# npm hangs on postinstall / unlock

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, virtualization

I have a Linux server that runs some virtual Machines using KVM. Host machine is a Debian derivate with kernel 2.6.32-32(-pve).

In roughly 75% of the times I run `npm install`, it hangs while installing modules. I ran it in silly debug level and it always hangs at the line

`npm info postinstall [module name]` (older npm versions)

or

`npm verb unlock done using [...]` (newer npm versions)

forever.

It happens in every project on the host machine and on the virtualized systems for every node and every npm version I have tested (a lot, including the newest ones (2.7.x atm)).

It also is not deterministic. Sometimes it works, sometimes not and most of the times it hangs on a different module.

On my dev machine (which is in the same network, running OS X 10.10) it works fine.

I am not behind any kind of proxy.

What could possibly be wrong here?

**EDIT**: For the time being I solved this problem by checking in all my dependencies as gzipped files using https://github.com/JamieMason/shrinkpack

Comment: Do you know what particular package's post-install this is hanging on? Also what is the node version? What is the output of ~/.npmrc? Have you tried doing `npm cache clean` to remove the lock files before running npm install?

Comment: The package on which it is hanging varies. I tried a lot of node and npm versions, as well as doing a `npm cache clean`. I'm going to check the ~/.npmrc output.

Comment: Just want to add that in general I found that the more the connection is stable the more the `npm install` is stable and does not get stuck, i tried with multiple versions of `npm` nothing helped only making my internet/intranet connection more stable (best wired).

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue for several hours, and couldn't work out what the problem was. I tried re-installing everything a few times, manually installing individual modules, switching from x64 to x86 versions of NodeJS, etc, and got nowhere.

In the end, I changed networks, from WiFi over ADSL2+ [~2mbps] to 4G Hotspot [~20mbps] and it worked in 30 seconds. No idea why, since it didn't seem like a network speed issue, but it solved the problem.

Hope this helps someone else, too!

Comment: I can confirm that. Changing from wifi to lan worked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on our Jenkins slaves based on Ubuntu, and it was solved by upgrading `npm`.

Default `npm` installed by `apt-get` has version `1.3.10` now, which is very old (shown by `npm --version`). There are at least two ways to upgrade it:

1. Run `sudo npm install -g npm` command. If you want to install a specific version you can run append it at the end of command: `sudo npm install -g npm@2.1.3`.
2. Or you could add NodeSource repositories using [these instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#usage-instructions) and run usual `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: I am sorry but I already tried a lot of npm versions (including the newest ones (2.7.x)) with no luck...

Comment: `npm install npm` feels weird, but it works... By the way, the reason for the old npm version might by that the `nodejs` package from `apt-get` is the LTS version of Node and probably uses npm from that time.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem on `Windows`. I deleted my `npm-cache` folder and reinstalled `npm`. Everything started working normally after that.
The `npm-cache` folder can be found at

```
<your-drive>\Users\<your-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

*Remember to turn on 'View hidden files because the AppData folder by default is hidden*

You can reinstall npm by using the command,

```
npm i npm -g
```

Comment: Reinstalling npm worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows make sure you are in a native CMD (not in VSCODE or whatever IDE). Also, try increasing the max memory limit for node:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same, switched my network from WiFi to 3G and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem, this is the issue on Github:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7862

There are some useful tips that seemed to help a few people.

For me doing $ npm install -g node-gyp  (as suggested here: http://gangmax.me/blog/2013/05/13/resolve-npm-update-node-gyp-hung-problem/) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just run

`npm cache clean`

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem in Windows. The solution was to restart after installing node and npm and then run command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a system restart did the work.
I ran `npm install --verbose` which suggested some lock on a file in `npm-cache`. And I think the system released the file (which was under use) after the system restart. I am using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning the project again and then run `npm install` to install the packages in your terminal.

Comment: npm cache clean --force. this also you can try

Comment: or change your network might be internet issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with npm v6, and it turned out I was just being impatient. I just needed to wait a little longer and it proceeded to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

works for me :)

Answer (score -1):

### => this method working with me When npm block in installation Package  for IONIC installation and ReactNative and another package npm.

you can change  temporary :
  npm config set prefix C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules2

- change the Path in Environment Variables  set C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules2
- Run the your command to install your package .
- open  file explorer copy the link  C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

  ok file yourpackage.CMD created another folder Created "node_modules2" in node_modules  and contain your package folder.
- copy your package file CMD to parent folder "npm"
- copy your package folder to parent folder "node_modules"
- now run npm config set prefix C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm
- change the Path in Environment Variables  set C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm
- now package working correctly with Command line

Comment: Maybe you could try to format it a bit better, and add some more in-depth details about the procedure you mention?